# ClangFormat Single Line While Loop Semicolon Issue

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, clang-format

I often have statements like:

```
...
// Wait until resource is not busy anymore
while (resource_busy());
...
```

for busy waiting. ClangFormat moves the semicolon into its own line:

```cpp
...
// Wait until resource is not busy anymore
while (resource_busy())
;
...
```

How can I stop ClangFormat from doing that? I can't seem to find the parameter I need to tweak. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This not a good practice. ; is not well noticeable and other developers may misread your code. Better if `while (resource_busy()) {}`. `{}` emphasis the loop performs no actions, this is not an error or typo, whereas most people consider `while(...);` as a typo.

Comment: Not sure if I can agree. Statements like that are quite common in the embedded world. For example: `while (EUSCI_B_I2C_isBusBusy(EUSCI_B0_BASE));` (I2C code for an TI MSP430).

Comment: And still: `while (resource_busy()) {}` will be broken down into two lines by ClangFormat as well. How can I get a single line while loop with ClangFormat regardless of using `{}` or `;`? There surely must be a way?

Comment: Ahh, finally found a similar question. Marking this as duplicate.

Comment: clang-format has the option AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine that makes it able to recognise empty { } and keep it on the same line.